# Calculating return addr in stack from a buffer pointer

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, stack

I am trying to smash stack and trying to bring SHELL reading from below link:
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html
I am sending arglen neg and successlully smash the stack and code is giving segfault. But I cannot calculate the RET Address where I should put SHELL code that I have. So in buffer after that distance I shall put the SHELL code.

```
int foo(char* arg, short arglen)
{
    char buffer[8];
    short maxlen = 8;
    int len;
    if (arglen < maxlen)
    {
        len = strlen(arg);
        printf("arglen =%d, buf size =%d\n", arglen, len);
        strncpy(buffer, arg, len);
    }else
        printf("foo finished. Everything is normal.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The `info frame` O/P of above code is putting break point in strncpy:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffc740:
 eip = 0x804854a in foo (target.c:17); saved eip = 0x804864f
 called by frame at 0xff80cd13
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0xffffc738, args: arg=0xffffc750 "1\300Ph//shh/bin\211\343PS\211ᙰ\v̀", arglen=-32549
 Locals at 0xffffc738, Previous frame's sp is 0xffffc740
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xffffc738, eip at 0xffffc73c
(gdb)
```

How Can I calculate the return address from `buffer` address?

[EDIT]

```
12345%n\x90\x90\x90\x90...\x90\x90SHELLCODE
```

Like this I want to put my buffer memory

Comment: Anything wrong in my Question? I can help clean if possible

Comment: Your code most likely won't work anyway, unless you rebuild your Linux kernel without the "no-execute on stack" protection that was introduced in the x86 processors ca 2001 (Intel slightly later).

Answer (score 0):

The call assembly instruction pushes the instruction pointer onto the stack and then places the address in the call instruction in the instruction pointer.
The normal function entry is as follows:

```
push bp
mov bp, sp
sub sp, n    ; n is the number of bytes for the local variables.
```

The stack from top to bottom now looks like:

```
arglen
arg
ret
bp
buffer
```

Buffer is the first local parameter. Then buffer + 8 + sizeof(void *) is the location of the return address